# Adding innerBlock with attributes on click in Wordpress Gutenberg Editor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am creating a gutenberg block with innerblocks. In this case the native `core/cover` block. I then add three innerblocks with the `TEMPLATE` variable, and load it in to `<InnerBlocks ...>`

My issue is, that when you add another cover block via editor, it does not have the `innerBlockPresets` which i defined. As far as I can tell `allowedBlocks` doesn't allow attributes.

I have to use the native cover block for this.
How can I solve this?

- Wordpress 5.9
- base created with `@wordpress/create-block`

**edit.js**

```js
import {useBlockProps, InnerBlocks} from '@wordpress/block-editor';

export default function Edit(}) {

    const blockProps = useBlockProps();
    const ALLOWED_BLOCKS = ['core/cover'];
    const innerBlockPresets = {'className': 'is-awesome', 'align': 'full'};
    const TEMPLATE = [['core/cover', innerBlockPresets], ['core/cover', innerBlockPresets], ['core/cover', innerBlockPresets]];

    return (
        <div {...blockProps}>
                <InnerBlocks
                    allowedBlocks={ALLOWED_BLOCKS}
                    template={TEMPLATE}
                    renderAppender={() => <InnerBlocks.ButtonBlockAppender/>}
                />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I figure a solution would be to create a custom innerBlock, add that to the allowedBlocks and only allow it to have a single innerBlock. This would encapsulate stuff a bit, but should work...
Any cleaner solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution could be to register a [block variation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-variations/) of `core/cover`, eg:

**index.js**

```js
wp.blocks.registerBlockVariation('core/cover', {
    name: 'cover-variation',
    title: 'Cover Variation',
    icon: 'star-filled',
    attributes: {
        className: 'is-awesome',
        align: 'full'
    }
});
```

This enables you to have a predefined set of attributes. Next, if `ALLOWED_BLOCKS` in InnerBlocks contains `core/cover`, only `core/cover` & your `cover-variation` (or any other variations of cover) can be added, eg:

**edit.js**

```js
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
import { useBlockProps, InnerBlocks } from '@wordpress/block-editor';

export default function Edit() {
    const ALLOWED_BLOCKS = ['core/cover'];
    const TEMPLATE = [
        ['core/cover', {
            className: 'is-awesome',
            align: 'full'
        }]];

    return (
        <div {...useBlockProps()}>
            <InnerBlocks
                allowedBlocks={ALLOWED_BLOCKS}
                template={TEMPLATE}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

[image]

An issue I've found with this approach is the variation cannot be set in `TEMPLATE`, as the block variation is registered after the core block but too late for InnerBlock template validation. If you try this, the InnerBlock template validation returns "*undefined*" when using a block variation and won't render. So to avoid this issue, in the `TEMPLATE`, set the same properties as your variation.

Comment: I tried this. The problem ist, that I can only initially add the block variations (via template). I was not able to do this on click. On click i seem to only be able to add the base block.
``ALLOWED_BLOCKS`` does not take block variations. Does it?

Comment: @Frizzant Did you remove your `renderAppender` as the default one would be fine for what you want to do, which then allows the base block + any variation of it. No, as far as I know `ALLOWED_BLOCKS` doesn't take variations, I can think of another (potentially awful way) where you create you own block that contains just the preset 'core/cover` then use your new custom block as the `ALLOWED_BLOCKS` to absolutely limit it to your desired attributes..

Comment: yeah this is actually what i ended up doing, because I see no other way of solving this.